# How to calculate length of common chord of two intersecting circles?

Tags: geometry, circles

> Two circles having radii $7$cm & $19$ cm are separated by a distance of $22$ cm between their centers. If they are intersecting each other at two points $P$ & $Q$ then what will be the length of the common chord PQ?
>
> a.) $\frac{9\sqrt{205}}{13}$
>
> b.) $\frac{8\sqrt{255}}{11}$
>
> c.) $\frac{9\sqrt{233}}{13}$
>
> d.) $\frac{8\sqrt{155}}{11}$

I tried this by assuming one circle to be centered at the origin but it's creating utter mess. I am 12th grade. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, one way to go through this is coordinate geometry, assign two circle along x-axis. Equation of common chord is S-S'=0 , and you are done but rather long, here's a link http://sakshieducation.com/Inter/Material/IIndYearEM/MathsIIB/System_of_Circles.pdf

Comment: you must search it in net before coming here..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$7^2-x^2=19^2-(22-x)^2$$
$$x=\frac{43}{11}$$
so
$$h^2=7^2-\frac{43^2}{11^2}=\frac{4080}{121}$$
$$h=\frac{4\sqrt{255}}{11}$$
hence
the Chord $PQ$ = $2h$

$$PQ=\frac{8\sqrt{255}}{11}$$

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Connect the centers and the intersection points.

[image]

Using this [enter link description here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron's_formula) you find the area to be $4 \sqrt{255}$. $22h/2$ will also be the area. So you find $h$ to be $4 \sqrt{255}/11$ But the chord is $2h$. So final answer

$$\frac{8 \sqrt{255}}{11}$$

Answer (score 0):

OK, i found a [general formula to compute the length of common chord of two intersecting circles](http://www.academia.edu/10798008/Mathematical_Analysis_of_Three_Externally_Touching_Circles_Derivations_of_inscribed_and_circumscribed_radii_for_three_externally_touching_circles_) radii $r_1, r_2$ separated by a distance $d$ between their center
$$=\frac{\sqrt{(d^2-(r_1-r_2)^2)((r_1+r_2)^2-d^2)}}{d}$$
inserting the values, $r_1=7, r_2=19$ & $d=20$, i get length of common chord
$$=\frac{\sqrt{(22^2-(7-19)^2)((7+19)^2-22^2)}}{22}=\frac{\sqrt{340\cdot 192}}{22}=\frac{8\sqrt{255}}{11}$$